# How can I simulate a print statement in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have some procedures where I would like to get some kind of acknowledgement after a condition has been assessed.

For example, the pusedocode would be like,

```
if ( select count(*) from assgn to where eid = 1 )  > 5
  print " the total number of projects employee working is more than 5 "
else
  insert the value into the assgnto table
```

How should I go about doing that in MySQL?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

If you do not want to the text twice as column heading as well as value, use the following stmt!

```
SELECT 'some text' as '';
```

Example:

mysql>SELECT 'some text' as '';
+-----------+
|           |
+-----------+
| some text |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: I like to make use of the column heading, e.g.: `SELECT 'is more than 5' AS ``the total number of projects the employee is working on``;`

Comment: @mvsagar so is it not possible to use `print` in `mysql`?

Comment: @Kasun Siyambalapitiya No it isn't.

Answer (score 31):

You can print some text by using `SELECT` command like that:

```
SELECT 'some text'
```

Result:

```
+-----------+
| some text |
+-----------+
| some text |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: so is it not possible to use `print` in `mysql`?

Comment: @kasun-siyambalapitiya No it isn't.

Answer (score 7):

This is an old post, but thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37378009/3347337) post I have found this:

```
\! echo 'some text';
```

Tested with MySQL 8 and working correctly. Cool right? :)

Comment: Very cool :) This feature is documented at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html.

Answer (score 0):

to take output in MySQL you can use if statement
SYNTAX:

```
if(condition,if_true,if_false)
```

the if_true and if_false can be used to verify and to show output 
as there is no print statement in the MySQL