# How to echo print statements while executing a sql script

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a simple sql script which needs to be executed against a MySQL database and we would like print log statements on the progress of the script (e.g. Inserted 10 records into foo or Deleted 5 records from bar). How do we do this?

1. I would like to know the syntax to be used for insert/update/delete statements.
2. How do I know about the number of rows affected by my statement(s).
3. I would also like to control printing them using a ECHO off or on command at the top of the script.
4. The script should be portable across Windows / Linux OS.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This will give you are simple print within a sql script:

```
select 'This is a comment' AS '';
```

Alternatively, this will add some dynamic data to your status update if used directly after an `update`, `delete`, or `insert` command:

```
select concat ("Updated ", row_count(), " rows") as '';
```

Comment: What should I do if I have to capture the number of rows affected from a certain update/insert/delete statement.

Comment: This adds an extra white space row. Is there a way to do this with out the extra row?

Comment: @John I have used `Attn` or `Note`.

Answer (score 38):

I don't know if this helps:

suppose you want to run a sql script (test.sql) from the command line:

```
mysql < test.sql
```

and the contents of test.sql is something like:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA;
\! echo "I like to party...";
```

The console will show something like:

```
CATALOG_NAME    SCHEMA_NAME            DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME      
         def    information_schema     utf8
         def    mysql                  utf8
         def    performance_schema     utf8
         def    sys                    utf8
I like to party...
```

So you can execute terminal commands inside an sql statement by just using `\!`, provided the script is run via a command line.

```
\! #terminal_commands
```

Comment: So long as you just need a message without any parameters, this works perfectly.

Comment: This works great. You say "provided the script is run via a command line" - how else would this be run? That is, under what circumstances would this not work?

Comment: This feature is documented at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html.

Answer (score 9):

What about using `mysql -v` to put mysql client in verbose mode ?

Comment: Having using Postgres most recently, `psql -e` or `-E` is the same thing; not sure what else `-v` will output, but this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 6):

Just to make your script more readable, maybe use this proc:

```
DELIMITER ;;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS printf;
CREATE PROCEDURE printf(thetext TEXT)
BEGIN

  select thetext as ``;

 END;

;;

DELIMITER ;
```

Now you can just do:

```
call printf('Counting products that have missing short description');
```

Comment: This seems a lot of extra steps, especially compared to solution from Craig Wayne

Answer (score 4):

For mysql you can add \p to the commands to have them print out while they run in the script:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `mysql`.`user`
\p;
```

Run it in the MySQL client:

```
mysql> source example.sql
--------------
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `mysql`.`user`
--------------

+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|       24 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use print -p -- in the script to do this example :

```
#!/bin/ksh
mysql -u username -ppassword -D dbname -ss -n -q |&
print -p -- "select count(*) from some_table;"
read -p get_row_count1
print -p -- "select count(*) from some_other_table;"
read -p get_row_count2
print -p exit ;
#
echo $get_row_count1
echo $get_row_count2
#
exit
```

Comment: I should also mention that this script could be run from a Windows or a Linux environment