# Run mysql commands in bash script without logging in or adding -u root to every command

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell

I'm writing a bash script to do some db stuff. New to MySQL. I'm on Mac and have MySQL installed via homebrew.

Am using username "root" right now and there isn't a pw set. I included the pw syntax below just to help others out that may have a pw.

**My goal is to have mysql commands be as "clean" as possible in my bash script**

Not a hige deal, but would like to do this if possible.

Example

```
# If I can do it without logging in (*ideal)
mysql CREATE DATABASE dbname;

# Or by logging in with - mysql -u root -pPassword
CREATE DATABASE dbname;

# Instead of
mysql -u root -pPassword -e"CREATE DATABASE dbname";
```

Tried to simplify it. I have a handful of things I gotta do, so would rather keep my code cleaner if possible. I tried logging in with the bash script, but the script stopped once logged into MySQL and didn't run any commands.

Another option I was considering (but don't really like) would be just to keep username and pw string in a var and call it for every commmand like so

```
# Set the login string variable
login_details="-u root -p password -e"

# example command
mysql $login_details"CREATE DATABASE dbname";
```

**So any ideas?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Write a new bash script file and run this file after putting all your commands into it. Don't forget to give right username and password in your bash script.

For bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -u root -pSeCrEt << EOF
use mysql;
show tables;
EOF
```

If you want to run single mysql command.

`mysql -u [user] -p[pass] -e "[mysql commands]"`

Example:

```
mysql -h 192.168.1.10 -u root -pSeCrEt -e "show databases"
```

To execute multiple mysql commands:

```
mysql -u $user -p$passsword -Bse "command1;command2;....;commandn"
```

Note: -B is for batch, print results using tab as the column separator, with each row on a new line. With this option, mysql does not use the history file. Batch mode results in nontabular output format and escaping of special characters. -s is silent mode. Produce less output. -e is to execute the statement and quit

Comment: Cool got your first method working. Thanks! By any chance do you know how to echo or print a string to the command line while in mysql?

Comment: Good to hear that it worked nicely for you. Yes follow this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147834/how-to-echo-print-statements-while-executing-a-sql-script if this doesn't work try the suggestions. Let me of any help 

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for "user4398985" answer, that helped me a lot. I also like to add some additional things to his answer.

```
mysql --defaults-extra-file=<cred_file> -P 3306 --database=<database> -Bse "command"
```

This way you can execute mysql commands without showing or typing password in the script and point your sql command to a specific database.

In here `<cred_file>` is the file that contains your credentials.
`<database>` is the specific database that you want to point your code.

Ex for cred_file:

```
[client]
user=<user>
password=<password>
```