# SQL IF statement with a print

Tags: mysql, sql

What am I doing wrong? It needs to display yes if more people are single than married and no if viceversa. I just want it to display yes or no only.

```
IF
select COUNT(StudMaritalStatus) from students WHERE StudMaritalStatus = "M"
<
select COUNT(StudMaritalStatus) from students WHERE StudMaritalStatus = "S"
Print 'Yes'
ELSE
Print 'No';
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147834/how-to-echo-print-statements-while-executing-a-sql-script

Comment: To clarify the error I am getting says I am using the wrong IF statement syntacs.

Comment: please post the syntax error statements.

Comment: Error 1064 to the right of IF

Comment: One thing you are doing wrong is that count(something) returns a number, and you are comparing it to the letters M or S.

Comment: post your fields in your database...

Answer (score 3):

You want something like this:

```
select case when married >= single then 'M' else 'S' end
from 
(
select sum(case when StudMaritalStatus = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) married
, sum (case when StudMaritalStatus = 'S' then 1 else 0 end) single
from students
) derivedTable
```

Tie breaking depends on your business requirements, which none of us know.

Answer (score 2):

well considering that MySQL uses:

```
 IF expression THEN
      expression        
    ELSE
 ENDIF;
```

you would be better of not doing it with a select statement

```
DECLARE married int, single int

SET married = select COUNT(StudMaritalStatus) from students WHERE StudMaritalStatus = 'M'

SET single = select COUNT(StudMaritalStatus) from students WHERE StudMaritalStatus = 'S'

IF married < single THEN 
  PRINT 'YES'
ELSE 
  PRINT 'NO'
END IF
```

In answer yes your syntax was wrong
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html

Comment: not the most elegant of solution but it shows him where his syntax was wrong and how to correct it.  @Dan your solution optimized to minimize data base calls.. figured simple to complex first :)