Logging the mariadb command and its output next to each other
Is it possible to log the mariadb command and its output next to each other, when the commands are source from a .sql file, just like bash -x:
$ printf 'echo abc\necho def\necho done!\n' | tee /tmp/test.sh
echo abc
echo def
echo done!

$ bash -x /tmp/test.sh
+ echo abc
abc
+ echo def
def
+ echo 'done!'
done!

My client is part of MariaDB of this version:
$ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.5.25-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2


Are you aware of the tee command in the mysql client? Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html

Yeah, I tried the tee command @BillKarwin, but since the commands are source from a .sql file, they're not printed to output, only the result data are.

You revealed in an edit that you are using MariaDB, not MySQL. I don't use MariaDB, and it's a different software product than MySQL. The two are not compatible. Solutions for one may not work for the other. I'll leave it to others to suggest a solution for MariaDB. Good luck!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147834/how-to-echo-print-statements-while-executing-a-sql-script may be of interest

@BillKarwin, the answer suggested by Allan, which is MySQL based, works nicely with my MariaDB, so I'm adding the tag back.
