# Show message in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

How do I show a message from a stored procedure?

What is the right syntax to display a message saying whether or not rows exist?

In SQL Server it's PRINT to show a message bat in WORKBENCH...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `new_proced` (
    in myid     int(3)
)
BEGIN
    if not exists (select id from table where id = myid)
then
    show message 'Row no exists';
else
    show message 'Row exists';
end if;
END
```

Comment: Stored procedures can't "show messages".  Then can return either an OUTPUT parameter OR a record set.  It's up to your application to determine what to do with the results.  That said, you can "print" a message which is similar to simply selecting some text: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912102/how-can-i-simulate-a-print-statement-in-mysql

Comment: Yes, but for this moment is not for aplication. I'm just testing my database. :) Thank's.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Not entirely sure why you would want to do something like that, but you could do something like this:
...

```
then
  select 'YOUR MESSAGE HERE'  
else
  select 'YOUR OTHER MESSAGE HERE'
end if
```

Or you could select 1 or 0, might be a little better...

Comment: Why would someone do that: Imagine you are working with large amount of data and you are using mysql terminal...and if you are also doing SQL-programming, there is a HIGH possibility that you will want to debug/show some output in some special cases, because with data so large, you just *can't* go through your data... BTW: I would do even `SELECT 'YOUR MESSAGE' AS error_message;` for better understanding of error in terminal/some sql admin :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no Proper output statement provide in MySQL like in Oracle, we have DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE. So, to display any messages on the console, you can use **SELECT** statement as:

`SELECT message;`

Eg:
`SELECT "WELCOME TO MySQL";`

Answer (score 1):

For debugging info from stored procedure in MySQL,there are following options through which you can do this.

1.Write into the file externally:

> select "your_message" as log into outfile '/temp/brajesh.txt';

2.Use select command to print message:

> select "result_message";

3.Use select command to print additional information with message:

> select concat("Hello ! :", result);

4.Create addition table temp and push all message into it:

> insert into temp select concat(result);

Example

```
drop procedure if exists display_name_procedure;
delimiter //
create procedure display_name_procedure(IN name_val varchar(65))
begin
declare result varchar(65);
set result := display_name_function(name_val);

create table if not exists temp (name_val varchar(65) not null);
insert into temp select concat(result);
select "penguin" as log into outfile '/temp/brajesh.txt';
select concat("Hello ! :", result);

end//

delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The full procedure is built in this code. You can modify this code per your requirement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertData
    @Title nvarchar(max),
    @Releasedate datetime2(7),
    @genre nvarchar(max),
    @Price decimal(18,2)
AS
BEGIN
   
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Movie WHERE Title = @Title)
    BEGIN
 
        INSERT INTO Movie (Title, Releasedate, Genre, Price)
        VALUES (@Title, @Releasedate, @genre, @Price);
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
   
        SELECT 'Already exists' AS Status;
    END
END
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DELIMITER //
 
create procedure 

insert_data_student1(student_name varchar(50),email varchar(50),group_id int)

 begin

     if not exists(select email from student where email="email")
     then
         insert into student(student_name,email,group_id) values (student_name,email,group_id);
     else
          select 'all reday exists';

     end if;
 end //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).