# Add message in stored procedure that the value exists already

Tags: mysql

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertData(@Sifra VARCHAR(50), @Opis VARCHAR(50), @Status BIT)

AS BEGIN

COMMIT TRANSACTION

DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(MAX)

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.OpstiniTBL WHERE Sifra = @Sifra AND Opis = @Opis AND Status = @Status)

```
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

  RAISERROR ('Шифрата веќе постои', 16, 1)

            RETURN 1
```

ELSE

BEGIN TRANSACTION

```
  INSERT INTO dbo.OpstiniTBL(Sifra, Opis, Status)

  VALUES(@Sifra, @Opis, @Status)
```

END

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039398/show-message-in-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertData(@Sifra VARCHAR(50), @Opis VARCHAR(50), @Status BIT)

AS BEGIN

BEGIN TRANSACTION

DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(MAX)

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.OpstiniTBL WHERE Sifra = @Sifra AND Opis = @Opis AND Status = @Status)
BEGIN
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
set @ErrorMessage='value exists'

END
ELSE
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO dbo.OpstiniTBL(Sifra, Opis, Status)

  VALUES(@Sifra, @Opis, @Status)
END


  COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

Comment: Oh thank you very much, this works, I was using RAISERROR but i didnt understand it very well so.. thanks gain.

Answer (score 0):

//and what could possibly go wrong here?

clConnection clConn = new clConnection();
            SqlConnection conn = clConn.openConnection();

```
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("InsertData", conn);
        comm.Connection = conn;

        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        comm.Parameters.Add("@Sifra", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = OObject.Sifra;
        comm.Parameters.Add("@Opis", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = OObject.Opis;
        comm.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = OObject.Status;

        try
        {
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            check = true;

        }
        catch (SqlException sqlexc)
        {
            // handle SQL exception
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use stored procedure name correctly here

```
   SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("YourStoredProcedure_Name", conn);
```