# getting error in mysql— #1064 error while creating trigger

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I need to create a trigger for a table called try.. which will execute after something is entered into the table..(I am using phpmyadmin mysql)
But i am getting `#1064` error while creating it..
My trigger contains

```
BEGIN
DECLARE aa decimal(4,3);
DECLARE bb decimal(4,3);
DECLARE cc decimal(4,3);
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT a,b,c FROM site;
OPEN cur1;
FETCH NEXT FROM cur1 into aa,bb,cc;
WHILE FETCH_STATUS=0 DO
PRINT aa;
END WHILE;
END
```

it shows an error like this

```
 MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 'aa; END WHILE; END' at line 9
```

I am a newbie to trigger..Help me... Thanks

Comment: Could be missing `;` for `END`

Comment: @Fred-ii- getting the same error after editing as you said

Comment: I've never worked with triggers but I do read up on them every once in a while and it seems like you're missing an `END WHILE` to go along with your `WHILE` in order to end it. So, try and change one of the `END` to `END WHILE` probably the one before the last one, so that it reads as `PRINT aa;
END WHILE 
END` - See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/while.html

Comment: @Fred-ii- SORRY i am getting the same error again at line 9

Comment: Ask the person who's given you an answer below then. I don't know triggers enough to help you any further.

Comment: @scragar need your guidance to solve this question..what was wrong with my code

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your while loop to something like

```
WHILE FETCH_STATUS=0 DO
//print here
END WHILE;
```

As specified in this link

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/while.html

In addition see this post about mysql print functionality

[How can I simulate a print statement in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912102/how-can-i-simulate-a-print-statement-in-mysql)

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, was traveling, are you still getting the error at the same place when using while do, end while syntax or has it moved around a bit.

Comment: OK also check the link in the second part of the post, mysql doesn't have a print command so you have to use select correctly

Comment: example from that link                                                   You can print some text by using SELECT command:

SELECT 'some text';  will print some text