# mysql transaction fails regardless of the code inside

Tags: mysql, transactions, syntax-error

I am trying to write a transaction in mySQL, but no matter what i put between the tags i have an error.

```
start transaction;
set @email = "FOO";
PRINT @email;
commit;
```

This block invariably produces the error:

```
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set @email_name = "FOO";
PRINT @email_name;
commit' at line 2
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set @email_name = "FOO";
PRINT @email_name;
commit' at line 2
```

This behavior occur no matter what code is placed in the transaction and even persists if there is noting there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I simulate a print statement in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912102/how-can-i-simulate-a-print-statement-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no PRINT, use SELECT instead.

Comment: start transaction; set @email = "FOO"; SELECT @email; commit;