# How can I change SELECT statement to IF statement in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

In mysql, I tried to print '-1' if 3 conditions are satisfied.

```
SELECT '-1' 
WHERE not exists(select * from acq_staff where acq_person_id = staffID) 
OR    not exists(select * from acq_training_course_session where training_course_id = course_id) 
OR    exists(select * from acq_training_enrolment where acq_staff_acq_person_id = staffID);
```

But how can I change this SELECT statement to IF statement so that if either those 3 conditions are satisfied, print -1 otherwise I am going to insert a data.

Sorry for not enough information

Comment: The logic seems off. Are you saying, there's no record in the `acq_staff` table NOR the `acq_training_enrolment` table having a given `staffID`. OR there's no record in the `acq_training_course_session` table having a given `course_id`. — What are you actually looking for? For example, "is Joe registered in course ABC?"

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles Thank you for the comment! and Sorry for the lack of information .

for example, I was going to insert a row into a table. 

IN staffID INT,
IN course_id INT,

these are parameters.

if staffID is not exists or course_id is not exists or course is full, then print -1

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles otherwise, I was going to insert a row with that two parameters.

Sorry if this is hard to understand :(

Comment: I missed the OR part. Makes more sense. — Question: how can you tell if the course is full?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles Oh Sorry there is a table with attribute 'max_number_of_employee' and "current_enroled_employee" :)

So that I checked max_number_of_employee == current_enroled_employee


Thanks ::))

Comment: How about ?
```INSERT INTO `table` (`value1`, `value2`) 
SELECT 'stuff for value1', 'stuff for value2' FROM `table2` 
WHERE <all the conditions>``` Notice that `<all the conditions> `could also be subquery.

Comment: The above will insert a row only when select statement returns a result set

Comment: Do you mean you want to write `CASE WHEN stuff = 'value' THEN stuff = '-1' ELSE 0 END`

Comment: @DivineCoder Thank you for the comment!

What I wanted is, writing the query that starts with IF() statement so that I can use ELSE :)
For example, IF the staff_ID,course_ID are already exists, print -1 otherwise, INSERT the staff_ID and course_ID into a table.

Thank you so much tho!!

Comment: @IbrahimHammed Thank you for the comment!

I was meaning I wanted to write a query that starts with IF() statement! instead of starting with SELECT so that I can use ELSE statement :)

Comment: I am sure you can not start your query with IF ELSE like in a programming language. For example here is grammer of SQL https://ronsavage.github.io/SQL/sql-2003-2.bnf.html. I see no way to start query with if else.

Comment: @심준호 you cant start SQL query with IF/ELSE except you write `SELECT CASE WHEN ...`

Comment: @DivineCoder Oh thank you so much for letting me know !! that's why I couldn't find information and I had no idea about it :)) By change, do you know alternative way to do that? 
Thank you so much!

Comment: @IbrahimHammed That's why I couldn't find the information!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @DivineCoder How about doing this?
1. Inserting data first with conditions.
2. print -1 or 1 depend on the conditions

Comment: I am very sorry but when you suggest a print, it's very hard for me think from your perspective. With SQL queries, It's easier to think in tables rather then with scalar values.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL [`INNER JOIN`](https://www.tutsmake.com/mysql-inner-left-right-joins-for-beginners/), along with [`WHERE NOT EXISTS`](https://mysqlcode.com/mysql-exists-and-not-exists-statements/), can be used to determine if there's an existing course, and existing staff, and that staff is enrolled in that course, and if not, [`INSERT`](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_insert_into_select.asp) the staff and course id in the enrollment table.

```
-- create
CREATE TABLE acq_staff (
  acq_person_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE acq_training_course_session (
  training_course_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE acq_training_enrolment (
  training_course_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  acq_staff_acq_person_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);

-- insert
INSERT INTO acq_staff VALUES (1), (2), (3);
INSERT INTO acq_training_course_session VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4);
INSERT INTO acq_training_enrolment VALUES (1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (3,1);

-- fetch 
INSERT INTO acq_training_enrolment (training_course_id, acq_staff_acq_person_id) 
SELECT 3, 1 WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * 
FROM acq_training_course_session
  INNER JOIN acq_training_enrolment 
    ON acq_training_course_session.training_course_id = acq_training_enrolment.training_course_id
  INNER JOIN acq_staff ON acq_training_enrolment.acq_staff_acq_person_id = acq_staff.acq_person_id
WHERE acq_training_course_session.training_course_id = 3
  AND acq_staff.acq_person_id = 1)
;
```

Try it here: https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3yk7xynkg

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! 

this is almost what I wanted !! 
But if the conditions I wrote on the question are not satisfied, I'd like to INSERT a row into a table! 

for example, if given staff_id,course_id are not exists, INSERT these into a table otherwise, print -1 

Thank you

Comment: What do you intend to `INSERT`, and in what table?

Comment: I intended to INSERT staff_id, course_id into staff_course_enrolment ! :)
if the staff_id, course_id are not exists in the company database, print -1 , otherwise INSERT staff_id, course_id into staff_course_enrolment.      Thank you so much !!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can do something like this: [How can I simulate a print statement in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912102/how-can-i-simulate-a-print-statement-in-mysql)

```
`mysql>SELECT 'some text' as '';
+-----------+
|           |
+-----------+
| some text |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)`
```

and just instead of `some text` set `-1`.

And one more thing i noticed in your question, that part "if those 3 conditions are satisfied" if you want all 3 conditions to be satisfied you need to change `OR` to `AND`. Because in your case, with `OR`, there needs to be satisfied only 1 condition, but with `AND` all 3 of them need to be satisfied.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! 

I edited my question all the 3 conditions -> either 3 conditions :)

I was able to print text with those conditions  but I'd like to change it to IF() statement .

for example, 

IF(3 or conditions) then select 'text'
else INSERT DATA into TABLE

Thanks :)

Comment: I've really tried to understand your needs, but looks like i can't. Have you tried doing it from the programming language? And if that doesn't work here are some `CASE` and `IF` statements in mysql: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-if-statement/ and here is for case: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-case-function/

Comment: Thank you for trying tho :)

I think CASE is not for my needs.
what I wanted is, change the query I wrote to the query start with IF() so that I can use else() statement :) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try that

```
select 
if(
    acq_staff.acq_person_id = staffID , '-1' , 
    if(
        acq_training_course_session.training_course_id = course_id , '-1' , 
        if(acq_training_enrolment.acq_staff_acq_person_id = staffID , '-1' , 'not exist')
    ) 
) as "check" from acq_staff , acq_training_course_session , acq_training_enrolment limit 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! 

That works!!

But I'm also wondering how to print -1 if the 3 conditions are satisfied or Inserting a row into table if the 3 conditions are not satisfied.

Thank you so much!!

Comment: just try to create a trigger before insert : https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/mysql-before-insert-trigger/

Comment: Oh then put all the conditions on trigger and only inserting statement in the procedure?!

Comment: well, you can put here the insert sql, for tell you how you can do that

Answer (score 0):

The question is about how to conditionally execute an insert query. In pseudo-code, the question asks how to do the following

```
flag = (SELECT ... WHERE <all the conditions are met>)
IF flag == 1
   INSERT INTO ....
ELSE IF flag == -1
   DO NOTHING
```

Now think about it this way

```
result_set = (SELECT ... WHERE <all the conditions are met>)
# result_set here is the actual rows we want to insert
# length(result_set) > 0 if conditions are met
# length(result_set) == 0 if conditions are not met

INSERT INTO ... (result_set)
```

or simply

`INSERT INTO ... (SELECT ... WHERE <all the conditions are met>)`

When `<all the conditions are met>`, the insert will actually have something to insert. Otherwise, it will have an empty result set so no rows will be inserted.

So use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... WHERE <all the conditions are met>` Syntax to achieve desired results. Unfortunately, this solution does not have a way to return back -1.

Comment: You are just amazing,, I haven't tried this yet but I learnt a lot from your answer,, Thank you so much and I'll try it